# Libgdx - How can I combine multiple tiles into a single tile

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite, tile

So I am working on a game and I need to get connected textures working.

The maps are randomly generated so all I have is a byte array of what tile should be where.

And I have an idea that if I split each tile into 4 8x8 tiles and combine them into a single 16x16 tile so I can connected textures with minimal work.

So my main question is how can I take a texture sprite sheet with 8x8 tiles then take for tiles and arrange them into a single 16x16 tile for use with a StaticTiledMapTile.

```
  MapLayers layers = map.getLayers();
    TiledMapTileLayer baselayer = new TiledMapTileLayer(128, 128, 16, 16);
    for (int y = 0; y < LevelHight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < LevelWidth; x++) {
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            Tile tile = getTile(x, y);
            cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(atlas.findRegion(tile.atlasName)));
            baselayer.setCell(x, y, cell);
        }
    }

public Tile getTile(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= 128 || y >= 128)
        return Tile.rock;
    return Tile.tiles[tiles[x + y * 128]];
}
```

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: No it works how it is because y is multiplied first then x is added.
I could make it more readable though by doing x + (y * 128)

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was a byte array : )

Comment: Yeah probably should have made that more clear lol. But yeah im just trying to combine 4 tiles into a single tile that I can add to an TextureAtlas.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this at runtime? Why not preprocess the image files so your TextureAtlas already has all the possible types of 16x16 tile? Anything you do at run time will either result in four times as many tiles drawn on screen, or processing all the simple tile images into a new texture to load which would result in the same thing as pre-processing, except with slightly longer load time.

Comment: There are over 300 combinations of tile. And all this would be done on runtime as I think its better then doing it on the fly like I was with the Java2D Version.

Comment: Unless there is a fast way to do this on the fly.